# appcelerator titanium JAVA_HOME not detected

Tags: java, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

When I am  testing java -version , javac -version im getting a proper version in the cmd output ., but when I run the app from appcelerator I'm getting this below error., JAVA_HOME has been set properly .

```
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

[ERROR] :  JDK (Java Development Kit) not installed.

[ERROR] :  If you already have installed the JDK, verify your JAVA_HOME environment variable is correctly set.
[ERROR] :  The JDK is required for Titanium and must be manually downloaded and installed from http://appcelerator.com/jdk.
```

Comment: Why have you tagged javascript?

Comment: Titanium is using JavaScript as the main language. But you are right, for this question the tag is not relevant

Answer (score 2):

Most of all, if you get proper outout for `java -version` or `javac -version` it doesn't mean `JAVA_HOME` environment variable had already set. If your PATH environment variable contains java / javaw / javac binaries, you can run it but `JAVA_HOME` hadn't set. You should check it with: `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

Other thing is, Appcelerator requires JDK (Java Development Kit). JRE is not enough. But it seems you have JDK, because javac is not part of JRE edition.

At last look for yourself the right version of JDK and Appcelerator you have downloaded. E.g. both of those are for 64-bit operating systems.

Related issues:
[1] https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-6020
[2] https://github.com/appcelerator/atom-appcelerator-titanium/issues/129

Comment: or if he is using Linux: `echo $JAVA_HOME` plus have a look at the .bash_profile settings at https://github.com/m1ga/from_zero_to_app/blob/master/installation.md#for-all-distros-if-you-dont-have-nodejs-v10x